# Rotating 2 boxes intersects

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

i'm learning Scenekit and trying to rotate objects.
Here are 2 boxes and rotating them counter-clockwise by Z axis using transform matrix and SCNTransaction. It works, but they intersect during animation.

```
//1st node
let g1 = SCNBox(width: 2, height: 2, length: 2, chamferRadius: 0.05)
g1.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
BoxNode1 = SCNNode(geometry: g1)
BoxNode1?.position=SCNVector3(x: 3, y: 0, z: 0)
BoxNode1?.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 1)
self.rootNode.addChildNode(BoxNode1!)

//2nd node
let g2 = SCNBox(width: 2, height: 2, length: 2, chamferRadius: 0.05)
g2.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
BoxNode2 = SCNNode(geometry: g2)
BoxNode2?.position=SCNVector3(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0)
BoxNode2?.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 1)
self.rootNode.addChildNode(BoxNode2!)

//rotation
var rot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI_2), 0, 0, 1)
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(10)
BoxNode2?.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(BoxNode2!.transform, rot)
BoxNode1?.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(BoxNode1!.transform, rot)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

it seems outer box's rotation radius varies during animation. how i solve this?

Adding those 2 nodes under another node as children and rotating parent node solves problem, but not my desire.

Answer (score 1):

`SCNBox` instances already have their center at `(0,0,0)` so you don't have to change their pivot.

Also, using the `rotation` or `eulerAngles` properties might be easier than using transforms and matrix multiplications.